# Can't make http request in cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, http, cordova, ionic-framework

This is an example of an HTTP request:

```
$http.get(config.domain + '/forums_index.xml').then (data) ->
   ...
.catch (err) ->
  console.log 'Huh ho, ' + err
```

And there is an interceptor like this:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Basic YXBwX2FuZF9tczpOESFtVlI0Yw=="
```

Then I run `ionic run android`, it run the app, but it keep on loading and loading.

```
$ adb logcat CordovaLog:D *:S
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
I/CordovaLog(17151): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
I/CordovaLog(17151): Found start page location: index.html
I/CordovaLog(17151): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
I/CordovaLog(17151): Found start page location: index.html
D/CordovaLog(17151): file:///android_asset/www/js/application.js: Line 3 : Running Application...
D/CordovaLog(17151): file:///android_asset/www/js/application.js: Line 19 : Run fired!
D/CordovaLog(17151): file:///android_asset/www/js/application.js: Line 324 : Hey!
D/CordovaLog(17151): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1154 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
D/CordovaLog(17151): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1147 : Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
D/CordovaLog(17151): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1147 : Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
D/CordovaLog(17151): file:///android_asset/www/js/application.js: Line 326 : Getting list
D/CordovaLog(17151): file:///android_asset/www/js/application.js: Line 336 : Huh ho, Error: The http request failed
```

[Here](https://github.com/vinz243/jvc) is the full source (some changes may happen)

Comment: Are you using Ionic.Platform ready? (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/) I didn't see it in your code. It handles deviceready which is a requirement for Cordova apps.

Comment: In their demo, i didn't see it either. But it turned out that i forgot to connect to my WiFi network ._.